# pyqtgraph runtime error: could not load plugin "xcb"

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

My Python environment:
Ubuntun 20.10, Python 3.8.6,

**pip freeze** output:

- PyQt5==5.15.4
- PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
- PyQt5-sip==12.8.1
- pyqtgraph==0.12.1
- PySide2==5.15.2
- PySide6==6.0.3
- shiboken2==5.15.2
- shiboken6==6.0.3

**python plotting.py**

Error message:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution in this link (https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/1220).

After the following installation, the PyQtGraph sample code starts working:

- sudo apt-get install -y libxkbcommon-x11-0 x11-utils
- sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libyaml-dev
  libegl1-mesa libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1
  libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xinerama0